# Default ubuntu to boot in startup manager causes ubuntu to not work anymore

Tags: startup, unix

I have installed ubuntu alongside os x. I can start it by pressing the option key during startup and choose the correct disk. Everything works.

Now I want to default the ubuntu disk. That works by pressing "Control" while choosing the disk in the startup manager and pressing enter.

My mac now boots default to ubuntu. But it does not work anymore. The login screen appears, but neither keyboard nor touchpad work. Also if I plug in an usb mouse, it does not light up.

Comment: The boot volume is stored in NVRAM. Have you booted to OS X and then set ubuntu as the startup disk and then tried power cycling and then a normal start?

Comment: Do you mean I should set ubuntu as default from within OS X? If yes, I do not know how to do that. The partition is not listed when setting the startup disk in OS X. Otherwise I did all that you said.

Comment: Yes - you have to set it as default. I can answer if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check:

1. [reset your NVRAM](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20224/can-not-set-startup-disk) since the startup disk is stored there
2. [set the desired startup disk from OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417) (or by [blessing it manually](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=bless) from OS X) after the NVRAM clear
3. use a third party boot manager - [Boot Runner](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner) is about the best there is, but you have lots of options from free to open-source

Comment: reseting my NVRAM did not help. I was unable to set the disk for startup using bless because it was not listed in /Volumes. I am currently fiddling around with refind.